# Create a random coding array using the alphabet and numbers from ASCII with a specified frame and no repeats in Java

Tags: java, character-arrays

I am coding in java for four months now - still a newbie! I want to create a randomised no-repeating array in Java with a frame to find coordinates. I have initialized the chars that I would like in the array however I persistently get stops, dashes and brackets etc in the print out. What am I missing? I do not want to go down the employing of libraries route.

```
final char[] randomSquare = {'C', 'O', 'D', 'I', 'N', 'G'};
// the Grid used that will be randomly filled
char[][] grid;

int A = 65;
int Z = 90;
int num0 = 48;
int num9 = 57;

// create a Random numbers generator
Random ran = new Random();

grid = new char[randomSquare.length][randomSquare.length];

// loop to print randomSquare header for grid array
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
    System.out.print("   ");
    System.out.print(randomSquare);
}   
System.out.println();

// print randomSquare at position 0 all the way down
for(int i = 0; i < randomSquare.length; i++) {
    // the letter at the beginning of the row
    System.out.print(randomSquare[i] + "  ");

    // the Grid contents for that line
    int index = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < randomSquare.length; j++) {

        if (A >= 65 && A <= 90){

            index = ran.nextInt(A + Z);
        }

        if (num9 <= 57 && num9 >= 48) {

            index = ran.nextInt(num0 + num9);
        }
        System.out.print("" + (char)index);
    }
    System.out.println();
    index++;
}
return grid;
```

Comment: First, you are using an if-statement for A, num9, etc but you're never setting these values again after you initialize them. Not sure what you need them for. Second, `ran.nextInt(int n)` will return a random number up to that number. So essentially, you can get all kinds of symbols. For example, `ran.nextInt(A + Z)` is get any number up to 155. #60 is a < sign. Check out http://www.asciitable.com/. You need to fix the `ran.nextInt()` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below fix your problem with chars outside A-Z and 0-9

```
for(int i = 0; i < randomSquare.length; i++) {
        // the letter at the beginning of the row
        System.out.print(randomSquare[i] + "  ");

        // the Grid contents for that line
        int index = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < randomSquare.length; j++) {

            if(ran.nextBoolean()){
            if (A >= 65 && A <= 90){

                index = A + ran.nextInt(Z - A);
            }
            }else
            if (num9 <= 57 && num9 >= 48) {

                index = num0 + ran.nextInt(num9 - num0);
            }
            System.out.print("" + (char)index);
        }
        System.out.println();
        index++;    }

    for(int i = 0; i < randomSquare.length; i++) {
        // the letter at the beginning of the row
        System.out.print(randomSquare[i] + "  ");

        // the Grid contents for that line
        int index = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < randomSquare.length; j++) {

            if(ran.nextBoolean()){
            if (A >= 65 && A <= 90){

                index = A + ran.nextInt(Z - A);
            }
            }else
            if (num9 <= 57 && num9 >= 48) {

                index = num0 + ran.nextInt(num9 - num0);
            }
            System.out.print("" + (char)index);
        }
        System.out.println()

;
        index++;    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, the code is much more accurate than what I was trying to implement. I just need to find a way to exclude repeat characters from being printed now;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this does what you expect it to do and it's unclear what you desire. I'm going to rework your code to generate random numbers or letters, but you will probably need to carefully consider your code.

```
 // the Grid contents for that line


//perhaps index isn't the best name
int index = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < randomSquare.length; j++) {

    //keep generating new indexe until we get one within desired range
    while (!(index >= 65 && index <= 90 || index <= 57 && index >= 48))
        index = ran.nextInt(Z-num0)+num0; // gives numbers in a range from num0 to Z (48 to 90)

    System.out.print("" + (char)index);
}
System.out.println();

//not sure why this would be necessary
index++;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to populate a random array from letters and numbers avoiding duplicates, well just try the fiollowing:

```
//The array containing letters and numbers.
char[] lettersAndNumbers = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

  // the new list to populate
List<String> lc=new ArrayList<String>();
Random ran = new Random();
int i=0;
while(i<20) {
      //Choose a random index for to take an element from the array
    int rand=ran.nextInt(lettersAndNumbers.length);
      //put this element in the list if it doesn't exist
    if(!lc.contains(String.valueOf(lettersAndNumbers[rand]))) {
         lc.add(String.valueOf(lettersAndNumbers[rand]));
         i++;
    }
}   

  //Convert your list to an array
Object[] myArray=lc.toArray();
for (int j=0;j<myArray.length;j++){
    System.out.println(myArray[j]);
}
```

- Create a char array that contains all letters and numbers.
- Create a List and populate it with random elements from this array (if they don't exist already in the list).
- Convert your list to an array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood correctly what you're trying to do. But if you want a Collection of something that contains unique references, don't use a List or an Array, use a  [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).